# How can I add a login sound to the login GUI screen on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, audio

I'm trying to add a login sound to Raspbian, but I have no idea how to do it. 
Just so you know, when I mean login sound I mean after you type you user name and password. Anyone got any suggestions.

---

If it helps, I have a:

Brand: Raspberry Pi

Model: B

Operating System: Raspbian "Wheezy"

Size: 8 Gigabytes

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the virtual console login, you could add a command to your `.bashrc` file to play a sound file. This will be played anytime you login or create a new terminal emulator window.

An example would be `mplayer login.ogg &`. You'll need a sound from somewhere.

Is there a reason for this, though? Something else may be more fitting.

Comment: what would the command be and were should I add it

Comment: Open `.bashrc` in your home folder with a text editor and add `mplayer /path/to/sound.ogg` to the very end (if the file exists. If it didn't already exist, creating a new `.bashrc` is fine). Remember you need a sound file already.

Comment: does it have to be .ogg? I also noticed that "mplayer" doesn't seem to be a real command.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit late! `mplayer` is not installed on most distros be default. Install it with `sudo apt-get install mplayer`. Anyway, did you find another solution or use `mplayer`? If this was how you solved your problem, please mark it as the answer! ;)

Comment: Possibly use aplay which is pre installed in raspbian